# How do I remove all numbers?

Tags: python

All numbers in this list need to be removed (the original is 88,779 lines long):

```
SMITH          1.006  1.006      1
JOHNSON        0.810  1.816      2
WILLIAMS       0.699  2.515      3
JONES          0.621  3.136      4
BROWN          0.621  3.757      5
DAVIS          0.480  4.237      6
MILLER         0.424  4.660      7
...
```

Comment: You appear to have confused this with a code-writing or tutorial service. It's not.

Comment: I do not need a tut i only asked how do i remove numbers in the script,  so i am only left with names in the list and no numbers.

Comment: Oh! Then: you do it by writing some code. If you don't know how to write that code, you *do* need a tutorial.

Comment: Have you considered using a split command Fred? Or perhaps regex if you want to preserve or use the numeric values? Also, @jonrsharpe, please strive to be tolerant of new users.

Comment: @Addison I have no problem with new users. However, I do object to users (of any experience) who ask bad questions. This shows no effort at all, and does not meet the guidance in [ask].

Comment: @jonsharpe I do apologize this is new to me so it would be kind to just be more tolerant of me.

Comment: The guidance isn't a secret, indeed you're given links to it while writing a question. You have nobody to blame but yourself if you couldn't be bothered to read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it line-by-line to avoid using more memory as the files get larger, and use regular expressions replacement with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to match numbers in different formats:

```
import re

with open('infile.txt', 'rt') as infile:
    with open('outfile.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            line_without_numbers = re.sub(r'\[0-9]*(\[0-9]*)?', '', line).strip()
            outfile.write(line_without_numbers)
```

I've also run `.strip()` on the string to remove the leading/trailing padding spaces for the numbers that have been removed.